# Event listener for detecting hour

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm doing a simple script for detecting when it's 12 o'clock, that it shows a certain div, if not that it remains hidden. So the general idea is this:

```
function displayDiv() {    
    d = new Date();
    if(12 === d.getHours()){
        idMain.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        idMain.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

But I want that in an event listener so when it's that hour it automatically displays the div or hides it. Something like:

```
document.addEventListener(d.getHour() === 12, displayDiv);
```

Or something like that but I don't know how to establish the parameters to get the desired response or for it to work.

Thanks

Comment: Do you care if the time is noon their time, or if it is noon your time?  Or should it be noon GMT?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) to run the function every minute (60000 milliseconds).

```
function displayDiv() {    
    d = new Date();
    if(12 === d.getHours()){
        idMain.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        idMain.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
setInterval(displayDiv, 60000);
```

Comment: I agree with this solution. Depending on the precision he needs, he might have to call the function every second (1000).

Comment: @AdamAzad That's 60 seconds.

Comment: Also, local time can be affected if the computer's time is not well configured. Time should come from the server once, and then checked every second (again, depending on precision)

Comment: @hev1, I totally messed up with the math. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know what I didn't think about that first. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @SistemasIntegrales No problem.

Comment: Something that wakes less often and doesn't have to run every minute could go like this: (1) At page load get the current time and calculate how long until the next 12:00 (2) set an interval ("interval_1") for _slightly less_ than that amount of time. (3) when that fires, set a new interval ("interval_2") for, say, every 10 seconds. (4) when _that_ fires, basically do `displayDiv()` and then `clearInterval(interval_2)`.

Answer (score 2):

I completely agree with Hev1 solution of using the `setInterval` (use his implementation). Here is some additional information though:

setInterval takes 2 arguments. The first argument is the callback function which you want to execute at a specific time interval. And the second argument is the amount of miliseconds you want the function to execute.

Also I want to point out if you ever are in need of clearing the interval there is also a function for this call `clearInterval`. You have to store the interval in an variable for this, here is an example:

```js
const myInterval = setInterval(increase, 1000);

let index = 5;

function increase() {
  if (index === 0) {
    clear();
  } else {
    console.log(index);
    index--;
  }
}

function clear() {
    clearInterval(myInterval);
    console.log('interval cleared');
}
```

After the interval is stored in a variable the `clear()` method gets called when the interval reaches 0. In the clear function `clearInterval` is called to remove the interval.

Answer (score 0):

We can put the if condition using following current time values. 
var dates = new Date();
var hours = dates.getHours(); var minutes = dates.getMinutes();